# How to convert a Delimited List of Mixed Strings to an array for powershell script

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm looking to solve a problem where I have a long file of comma-delimitted ordered 8-digit numbers and ranges (with leading zeros), as below:

```
00001253,00001257-00001268,00001288,...,02154320,02154321,02154323-02154327,...
```

I want to 
(a) store any values that aren't ranges as tokens in a PowerShell array while retaining leading zeros 
and 
(b) expand ranges to all of their corresponding values and store the tokens in the same array. Here's the PowerShell "script" I threw together for my purpose so far:

```
$refids = @(ARRAY_DERIVED_FROM_ABOVE_LIST)

foreach ($refid in $refids) {
New-Item c:\scripts\$refid.txt -type file -force -value "KEY:$refid"
}
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this, maybe:

```
$string = '00001253,00001257-00001268,00001288,02154320,02154321,02154323-02154327'

$string.split(',') |
foreach {
  if ($_.Contains('-'))
    {
     invoke-expression ($_.replace('-','..')) |
     foreach {'{0:D8}' -f $_}
    }

  else {$_}
 }

00001253
00001257
00001258
00001259
00001260
00001261
00001262
00001263
00001264
00001265
00001266
00001267
00001268
00001288
02154320
02154321
02154323
02154324
02154325
02154326
02154327
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance - that seems to provide for a workable solution

Answer (score 1):

Mjolinor's answer is very good. Some people refrain from using `Invoke-Expression`. Here is another example that accomplishes the same thing while showing a *slightly* different approach.

```
$string = '00001253,00001257-00001268,00001288,02154320,02154321,02154323-02154327'

$string.split(',') | ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Contains('-')){
        $_.Split("-")[0]..$_.Split("-")[1]
    } Else {
        $_
    } 
} | ForEach-Object{ Write-Output ([string]$_).PadLeft(8,"0")}
```

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for your help also - I implemented a satisfactory solution with Mjolinor's response. Is there a reason to refrain from using 'Invoke-Expression'?

Comment: You want to avoid doing an Invoke-Expression on user generated input (e.g. by importing a csv file, or doing a Read-Host) because a user could input powershell or command code that would then be executed.  This appears to be machine-generated input.